# Use exist to check if Simulink-Block has parameter 'SampleTime'

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing, simulink

I want to write a function that automatically changes the parameter `SampleTime` of all blocks in my model to a specific value. I can use `find_system` to find all blocks and then I can loop through all blocks and use `set_param('Blockpath','SampleTime','0.001')`. But if I do this and the block does not have a parameter called `SampleTime`, it'll make my program crash.
So my question is how can I find out if the parameter exists before setting it? I tried something like `exist(['blockpath','/SampleTime'])`, but it didn't do what I expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `get_param('blockpath','ObjectParameters')` to get a struct with all parameters and then use `isfield` to check if you can find `SampleTime`.

I think what you are doing is not a good idea. In typical simulink models, you have the sample time set only at very few places, running all other models with inherited sample time. In most cases, it is not a problem to change these few places.

If you have to many blocks or you frequently change the sample time, better use a workspace variable or a mask parameter. Set all blocks to to have sample time `x` and put `x=0.01` in your base work space to set it for all blocks.

Comment: Well, I am supposed to write the variable 'sample_time' into each block, that I'm putting into the model. Since I'm too lazy to do this, I want to be able to just write this variable into all blocks, after I built the model. I thought this would be a nice and easy way of doing the Job and additionaly it makes sure, I don't Forget to set the sampletime of any block.  
Thanks for your help @Daniel.   
EDIT: I know that I could just set the models SampleTime, but I'm supposed to do it this way and I don't really know why.

Comment: Most blocks have a default sample time of `-1`, which means *inherited*.  In this way you only need to change the sample time of the most upstream block, not all blocks.  That is the correct way to be lazy.  @Max, whoever has asked you to do it the way you are doing it either doesn't really know how to use Simulink, or when they say "change all block sample times" is testing to see if you know that all block sample times are all changed if they are set to inherit and only the most upstream block is changed.

Comment: To verify all blocks run with the same sample time, go to display->sample time all. The colour will indicate the sample time. More important, the legend will show no other sample time. This way you know there is no block hidden in a subsystem you forgot to change.

Comment: @PhilGoddard I'm fully aware about this behaviour. I already discussed it with the person who gave me this task and nevertheless he asked me to do it this way. His argumentation was something about translating the model into c-code with real-time-Workshop, but as I said before, I didn't really get it

Comment: @Max: There is no reason not to use inherited sample times. The person telling you to do change all sample times does not know how inherited sample times work. There is absolutely no difference in the code generation process between an inherited and an explicit configured sample time.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Daniel's answer, if you really must do this, which for reasons given in the comments to @Daniel's answer is a bad idea, then the simplest approach is

```
% Define the new value as a string
>> newSampleTime = '10';
% Find all blocks in the model
>> allBlocks = find_system(gcs);
% Identify the blocks that have a SampleTime property
>> blockIdx = cellfun(@(c)isfield(get_param(c,'ObjectParameters'),'SampleTime'),allBlocks);
% Change the sample time
>> cellfun(@(c)set_param(c,'SampleTime',newSampleTime),allBlocks(blockIdx));
```

Comment: Well, @Daniel actually told me everything I needed already, but +1 for the fancy `cellfun` ;)